# Bootstrap Button переключает display

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap

Здравствуйте.

Нужно сделать чтобы при активации одной из 4-х кнопок открывался отдельный display и скрывался прошлый активный display.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно это реализовать на JS?

Пример кнопок такой (работает на бутстрапе)
https://jsfiddle.net/35r3zbtp/

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('#tabs label').click(function() {  
  $('.btn-danger').removeClass('btn-danger');
  $(this).tab('show').addClass('btn-danger');
});
```

```css
#tabs label input{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="tabs" class="nav nav-tabs btn-group">
  <label class="btn btn-primary btn-danger" id="option1" data-target="#content1">
    <input type="radio" name="options"> Параметр 1
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary" id="option2" data-target="#content2">
    <input type="radio" name="options"> Параметр 2
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary" id="option3" data-target="#content3">
    <input type="radio" name="options"> Параметр 3
  </label>
</div>
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="content1">Tab content 1</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="content2">Tab content 2</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="content3">Tab content 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: а как сделать, чтобы кнопки изменялись? как здесь? http://forts.pro/